# Throwing an exception from Q_INVOKABLE method?

Tags: c++, qt, exception, qml

Trying to understand the best practices for a Qt/QML based application, where we have methods marked as `Q_INVOKABLE`. What are the ramifications if we throw an exception from one of these methods?

```
class Class
{
    ...
    Q_INVOKABLE void method() { throw std::logic_error(); }
};
```

Can QML handle this error, or will I crash the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Q_INVOKABLE` macro just marks up the function so that it can be called by using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`. It doesn't really change how exceptions are dealt with in Qt.

For that, it's important to distinguish between slots that are called via a connection, and those that are invoked directly as normal functions. If a method is invoked through a signal-slot connection, it is undefined what happens when you throw an exception, unless you actually handle the exception within the slot. I.e., in a slot you *must* write:

```
void Class::method() {
    try {
        // code that might throw logic_error
    } catch (std::logic_error &err) {
    }
}
```

You cannot omit the `catch()` statement.

On the other hand, if the method is called directly as a function, then a bare throw is fine. However, it must be caught and handled wherever the method is called. I.e., you must write:

```
try {
    obj.method();
catch (std::logic_error &err) {
    // error-handling
}
```

This is really all because error handling in the Qt application event-loop isn't well-defined. See the [docs on Qt 5.9](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html) for more information.

Comment: I agree with your answer on how it works. That being said, I do not see the point of implementing a function that does some work, then at some point throws ,  and catch the exception within the function itself. In this case handling the erroneous case with an standard if then else  seems to make more sense ?

Comment: So to read between the lines -- if we call a C++ method from QML that throws an exception, the behavior is undefined?

Comment: @sandwood A common example would be a slot that interfaces with some external library which does throw exceptions. Qt itself (almost) never throws in the standard build, but many third-party libraries use exceptions liberally.

Comment: @yano Yes, that seems right. All exception handling should be done inside the C++ classes, if you’re calling them from QML.